# How do Managed Metadata terms with Term Reuse behave in search results?

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, refinement-panel, term

I'm trying to handle the following scenario:

- use the same Managed Metadata term in multiple Term Groups via Term Reuse
- configure multiple Content Types to use different instances of the reused term (i.e., different Term Groups for different Content Types, but same term reused)
- allow search results to be quickly filtered across content types for all instances of the reused term

If I get through points 1 and 2, what I don't know is if I click to filter on the reused term in the Refinements panel, should the result set include only content types to which the instance of the reused term belongs, or should it include any content type which uses any instance of the reused term? What factors might affect this behavior? Does this behavior change if I were click on one "instance" of the term vs. in e.g. an Enterprise Keywords-style refinement?

I guess another way to ask this is: if I want to search for all content that's tagged with a particular Managed Metadata tag, do reused terms play nice (can I pick one and have it hit all items), or do I effectively have to search each instance of the reused term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reused terms do play nice, the search crawler is very advanced and plays nice when configured well with everything.

This is the technet post on search + metadata hope it helps (Which covers different names for the same things)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262933%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Your 3 OOTB yes and no, it depends on the actually user experience you are going for, I hope I have covered 1 and 2 though.

Comment: Thanks, @HughWood. From the [2010 version of this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097%28v=office.14%29.aspx):
"...three different document types might have different names for the property that identifies the author. One document type might name this property Author, another Writer, and a third Property3. Although all three are crawled properties, only the documents with the Author property appear in search results when a user queries by author. To ensure that all documents appear in search results, map each of these crawled properties to the Author managed property."